# How to restore Windows 10 GPT boot config using command line?

Tags: windows-10, boot, cmd.exe, mbr, gpt

Long story short, windows 10 GPT drive can't boot, and can't access drive in question from command line, only X:\ . I have the option to repair/rebuild MBR using live ISO but its a GPT drive, is this safe?

It made a log of the errors but I scrolled through it and didn't see any helpful info. If someone could double check this for me that would be great, [Windows 10 startup error log](https://pastebin.com/M6XaSK1q)

So my problem happened when trying to add a new drive to windows. I was able to add the drive without problems using windows 10 disk management, and deleted the existing volumes on the new drive and made it a blank drive full of unallocated, unformatted space.

On restart the PC performed a disk check. The disk check found some discrepancies and took action to correct those.

After the restart from disk check it attempted to boot back into windows 10 but ran into some startup errors. It tried to detect and fix the problem but was unsuccessful.

After those messages it leaves me on a screen saying "sorry can't boot...."
and has the error "BAD_SYSTEM_CONFIG_INFO".

I have tried booting into safe mode without any luck. I have also tried recovery usb and disc startup repair options but to no avail.

I am able to reach a command line from advanced options on the error screen, and also from this [Windows 10 rescue ISO](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/27180-windows-10-recovery-tools-bootable-rescue-disk.html), but in both command prompts, it shows me X:\ drive. I am unable to reach the drive in question, even though I can see it from partition assistant on the windows 10 rescue ISO I mentioned earlier.

If this were a MBR drive, I would just try to restore the MBR using live ISO repair options. But I believe the corrupt windows 10 drive is GPT, and the ISO's I have only have MBR options. Could I switch to MBR if necessary without any repercussions?

I am able to see the windows 10 corrupt drive just fine from a windows 7 drive I have in the PC also, so I know all the files are still there and the drive is intact, so it seems to definitely be a boot config issue.

I would really prefer to not have to re-install just because windows broke itself, and seeing as the drive itself is still fine. So any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to convert MBR to GPT (or vice versa) you have to format boot partition and clean install Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Catalog has MBR2GPT.exe that circumvents the reformat and reinstall problem. Be certain to pick up the description/instruction paper before jumping in with both feet. You will need the command line parameters.
Also, use a system image for 'recovery' rather than a clean install. This will save you days of reconfiguring a 'default' OS and restoring all your data files.